# How to change actionbar's icon interval in style.xml?

Tags: android

I am studing android. I have some questions about action bar. I make action bar and change theme using style.xml.

This is my style.xml.

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">#FFFFFFFF</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">left</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

And this is a main.xml for action bar.

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">#FFFFFFFF</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">left</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

And, I have a 3 button on action bar. I rellay want to chang interval of each icons.

How can I do that? I dont want use custom_layout!

Comment: change inteval??? What do you wan to acheive??

Comment: I means that interval of icons. From : [Item1] [Item2] [Item3]  >> To : [Item1]　　　　     [Item2]　  [Item3]

Comment: to set margin or padding. plus I want to set align left...